# The status code is always 202 and response body is empty

Tags: python-requests, zeep

I am trying Python zeep client for SOAP XML testing, but it always return status code 202 and response body blank.
I am using zeep as follows

```
 wsdl_url = "https://6etestr4xapi.test.com/SessionManager.svc?wsdl"
    
    # Set Method Urls
    login_test = "https://6etestr4xapi.test.com/Logon"
    logout_test = "https://6etestr4xapi.test.com/Logout"
```

The logon method is working fine and it return the response correctly , . i.e. it return Signature

Then I am passing this signature to the header of Logout method.
The expected request XML for Logout method is

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
  <h:ContractVersion xmlns:h="http://schemas.test.com/WebServices">0</h:ContractVersion> 
  <h:EnableExceptionStackTrace xmlns:h="http://schemas.test.com/WebServices">false</h:EnableExceptionStackTrace> 
  <h:MessageContractVersion i:nil="true" xmlns:h="http://schemas.test.com/WebServices" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" /> 
  <h:Signature xmlns:h="http://schemas.test.com/WebServices">ZsRDVUlo2nI=|XRCwPaaG4S8TlGvRCxBX9QYW18Muyh3sP1gHoj+IHe5SNcsr6cV/CGrWSTX1xqz8LOsW3D5wMPZ4t6mPGBecUOK+ZqhlTCqIk3lYFK9Kewr6QzOwkA90GuJ34mvCO83gZ+Fk+UcGG9k=</h:Signature> 
  </s:Header>
 <s:Body>
  <LogoutRequest xmlns="http://schemas.test.com/WebServices/ServiceContracts/SessionService" /> 
  </s:Body>
  </s:Envelope>
```

Creating header like this

```
    header_logOut = zeep.xsd.Element(
    "Header",
    zeep.xsd.ComplexType(
        [
            zeep.xsd.Element(
                "{http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing}Action", zeep.xsd.String()
            ),
            zeep.xsd.Element(
                "{http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing}To", zeep.xsd.String()
            ),
            zeep.xsd.Element(
                "{http://schemas.test.com/WebServices}Signautre", zeep.xsd.String()
            ),
        ]
    ),
)
```

and

```
 header_value_logout = header_logOut(Action=logout_test, To=service_url, Signautre=result)

    with client.settings(raw_response=True):
    result1 = client.service.Logout(
_soapheaders= [header_value_logout]
)
```

This code:

```
 for hist in [history.last_sent]:

    print(etree.tostring(hist["envelope"], encoding="unicode", pretty_print=True))
```

prints xmls as:

```
 <soap-env:Envelope
    xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap-env:Header
        xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
        <Header>
            <wsa:Action>https://6etestr4xapi.test.com/Logout</wsa:Action>
            <wsa:To>https://6etestr4xapi.test.com/SessionManager.svc</wsa:To>
            <ns2:Signautre
                xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.test.com/WebServices">vINTd4zRrqc=|Sl7IkpH1WmPHbaRGBh65YHyavsGcpp3GuOyBX8mpOx9KHKk1C5En1ItoYCMeqUc44QvaVsIxDosUNQcxQ25GLQZi0hU2AqeEm/VEILWP0vvihY5q3Bgr79L8tQLmPT8mH5TERxFumdg=
            </ns2:Signautre 
        </Header>
        <wsa:Action>http://schemas.test.com/WebServices/ISessionManager/Logout</wsa:Action>
        <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:85edb9f6-2500-443d-942b-8bdbe414ff0d</wsa:MessageID>
        <wsa:To>https://6etestr4xapi.test.com/SessionManager.svc</wsa:To>
    </soap-env:Header>
    <soap-env:Body>
        <ns0:LogoutRequest
            xmlns:ns0="http://schemas.test.com/WebServices/ServiceContracts/SessionService"/>
        </soap-env:Body>
    </soap-env:Envelope>
```

and `print(result1)` gives:
<Response [202]>

and `print(result1.content)` prints
b''

Anyone, please help out here what is wrong with the implementation ?